# Ожидание добавления данных, если они используются где-то

Tags: c#

У меня есть событие, которое добавляет в список типа `List` данные. И во всём остальном коде я использую этот список. Получаю, конечно же, эксепшены, если использую список в момент его пополнения. Как можно реализовать момент, чтобы все места, где я `List` пополняю, ожидали, если он где-то в данный момент используется?
Только начинаю сталкиваться с многопоточностью, поэтому вопрос может быть глупый.

Пример, функции выполняются в разных потоках

```
public void eventValue(int value)
{
    list.Add(value)
}

public void nameFunt()
{
    ...
    list.Select(.....);
    ...
}
```

Получаю эксепшн, если использую `Select` и в этот же момент вызывается другая функция, которая добавляет элемент.

Comment: Можно использовать блокировку. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @becouse ну вот блокировку ты используешь, как я понимаю, если у тебя есть общий код и его используют разные потоки, а если у меня есть объект, которые используется в разных функциях, в разных частях кода и его надо как-то использовать только по очереди каждым событием\потоком

Comment: Если у тебя всего 1 поток, то ты не можешь одновременно делать несколько вещей с листом :D Если бы привёл упрощённый код того, что у тебя имеется, было бы круто

Comment: @Kamushek написал пример

Comment: @Fresto используй блокировку

Comment: либо же используй, к примеру, семафор https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.8.php

Comment: @AlexSherzhukov, обычно в C# не принято использовать симофоры для таких дел :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь установить блокировку.

```
private object _lock = new object();    

public void eventValue(int value)
{
    lock(_lock)
        list.Add(value)
}

public void nameFunt()
{
    ...
    lock (_lock)
    {
        //Но т.к. LINQ имеет отложенное выполнение он ничего не вычисляет тут.
        //Следовательно lock не спасёт, т.к. нам нужно закончить итерацию внутри блокировки (нужно сказать LINQ, что нам нужен результат уже сейчас)
        //Для этого преобразует результат в нужную коллекцию сразу (в любую коллекцию ну или пол)

        list.Where(...).Select(.....).<любые обработки>.ToArray();
    }
    ...
}
```

Скорее всего необходимости именно в `List` нет, поэтому вы можете использовать также `ConcurrentQueue`. Подробнее [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: А, ты используешь lock с одним и тем же объектом (_lock), и во всех местах в коде если этот объект занят, то в другом месте будет блокировка?

Comment: Да, в этом ведь и смысл блокировки :D Если использовать с разными объектами, то они друг о друге не узнают)

Comment: Я думал, что объект ты создаешь по приколу, и lock использую в тех местах, где потоки используют один и тот же код.
А оказывается lock можно использовать и глобально с одним и тем же объектом :D
Спасибо большое за пример!)

Comment: Блокировки работают на объектах из кучи, т.к. у каждого объекта в куче есть поле SyncBlockIndex, которое указывает на индекс объекта во внутреннем массиве CLR. А если использовать разные объекты, то они будут содержать разные индексы и никак не будут блокировать друг друга :3

Comment: @Fresto Или можно юзать ReaderWriterLock (для многих читателей и одного писателя), или использовать потокобезопасную коллекцию, типа ConcurrentBag

Comment: Да, ты можешь использовать `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (не Slim версия имеет проблемы с производительностью), а из потокобезопасных коллекций ты можешь выбирать любую, которая удовлетворяет твоим бизнес требованиям с:

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо большое за советы, буду изучать всё это, я так понял, тема слишком обширная

Comment: @Kamushek да, про Slim хорошее замечание, я бы тоже Slim выбрал (там разница в том, что Slim версия захватывает блокировку чуть позже, то есть для очень быстрых операций до блокировки дело может не дойти, за счет чего Slim версия лучше для короткиз операций, для долгих операций по сути не важно какую структуру брать), спасибо.